# Pass multiline variables between jenkins jobs

Tags: bash, shell, variables, jenkins

I've created 2 jenkins jobs - the first should create a variable from command's output.
This output will be of 5 lines.

Then, I would like to pass this variable to the second downstream job which should get this string exactly as it should be (With 5 separated lines).
I configured the first job to send the env var to a properties file.
e.g:
[image]

Then I used the EnvInject plugin and load this properties file with the "Inject environment variables".

[image]

As a post build action I use "Trigger parameterized build on other projects" with Parameters from properties file.

[image]

In the second job I get the variable as a 1 line variable not multiline.

Do you know how can I configure the variable to be sent exactly as it is?

Comment: Are the slashes supposed to be new lines or do you want the \'s preserving in the output text?

Comment: The \'s supposed to be new lines (I also tried \n)

Comment: `A="aaa\nbbb\nccc"` will work, or you can use two `\\`s instead

Comment: or just not use any slashes at all it will preserve the new lines as you have it quoted. Using \ and -e will have the problem you've got